# Jupyter lab running in ubuntu screen gets terminated when browser window is closed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a jupyter lab running in a screen on a server, which I am starting with `jupyter-lab --ip=my_ip --port=7778 --no-browser  script.ipynb` Then, I am opening it in my local browser via ssh. All printed output is retained, even when I close the browser window; e.g. if my script is finished running and produces output, I can close the browser window and the output will be there the next time I open the window.

However, I want to be able to start the execution of the script, leave it running on the server, close the browser window and leave it running, for example over night.
Is there an option I could use for that?

Comment: @darthbaba I thought so too, but if I close the browser window, the script terminates

Comment: maybe it is killing the kernel try this ```nohup jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=xxxx --no-browser &```  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976014/15751564